# Web Service Call with CLR Table Valued Function

Tags: c#, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

I'm trying to put together a few TVR's and I'm persistently getting the following error:

> An error occurred while getting new row from user defined Table Valued Function :
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char' to type 'ResultRow'.
>
> System.InvalidCastException at CLR.WorkFunctions.FillRow(Object resultsObj,
> SqlString& policyURL, SqlString& fileCachePath, SqlString& identity,
> SqlString& format, SqlString& userName, SqlString& password, SqlString& data)

I'm attempting to call a web service that does some work on the passed data and then load the returned values into an Enumerator. However, as shown above, I'm getting a typing error repeatedly and at this point I'm not sure why. My thought was it was getting upset because I was trying to fill the rows with strings rather than SqlStrings, so I changed that. However, the web service only accepts the parameters as strings, so I have to convert them over on the web service call. Here's my code:

```
public class WorkFunctions
    {
        private class ResultRow
        {
            public string PolicyURL;
            public string FileCachePath;
            public string Identity;
            public string Format;
            public string UserName;
            public string Password;
            public string Data;
        }
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(
               FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",
               TableDefinition = "policyName nvarchar(500), fileCache nvarchar(500), 
               identity nvarchar(500), format nvarchar(500), userName nvarchar(500), 
               password nvarchar(500), data nvarchar(500)")]
            public static IEnumerable Work(SqlString serviceURL, SqlString policyURL, SqlString fileCachePath, SqlString identity, SqlString format, SqlString userName, SqlString password, SqlString data)
           {
              IEnumerable values;

              try
                {
                    CLR.Work.WorkService.WorkMethods workMethods = new CLR.Work.WorkService.WorkMethods();
                    workMethods.Url = Convert.ToString(serviceURL);
                    values = workMethods.Work(Convert.ToString(policyURL), Convert.ToString(identity), Convert.ToString(format), Convert.ToString(userName), Convert.ToString(password), Convert.ToString(fileCachePath), Convert.ToString(data));
                }
              catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   return "Failed to return data";
                }

              return values;
          }

            public static void FillRow(Object resultObj, 
              out SqlString policyURL, out SqlString fileCachePath, 
              out SqlString identity, out SqlString format, 
              out SqlString userName, out SqlString password, 
              out SqlString data)
                 {
                   ResultRow resultRow = (ResultRow)resultObj;

                   policyURL = new SqlString(resultRow.PolicyURL);
                   fileCachePath = new SqlString (resultRow.FileCachePath);
                   identity = new SqlString (resultRow.Identity);
                   format = new SqlString (resultRow.Format);
                   userName = new SqlString (resultRow.UserName);
                   password = new SqlString (resultRow.Password);
                   data = new SqlString (resultRow.Data);
            
                }
      }
}
```

This is my first time working with TVF's and I'm at a bit of a loss regarding what could be causing this issue at this point. If anyone could provide some ideas, I'd be appreciative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for the most immediate issue is that the `workMethods.Work()` method does not return the same type as what you have defined as `ResultRow`. Whatever is being returned by `workMethods.Work()` and is being assigned to `values` is being returned as the result, and that gets sent to the FillRowMethod as the first parameter of type `Object`. Along those lines, you should probably remove the `IEnumerable values;` and `return values;` lines and then do something like:

```
ResultRow _Row = new ResultRow();

...

_Row = workMethods.Work(...);

yield return _Row;
```

Also, there is no need to use `Convert.ToString()` on any of the `SqlString` input parameters. All of the `Sql*` types have a `.Value` property that returns the expected .NET type. So just use `serviceURL.Value`, `policyURL`, etc.

Finally, why are the output fields pretty much the same as the input parameters? Seems like an odd signature.

P.S. If you are wanting / needing more info on working with SQLCLR in general, I am writing a series on this topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/). That site does require free registration in order to view their content (but it's worth it as there is an amazing amount of info in the various articles and forums).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

The web service function returns a string, and changing the web service isn't an option, so I can't change it to type ResultRow either. Would the best path forward be to somehow use a List of strings?

Also, thanks for the heads up regarding the knowledge base. That sounds tremendously useful.

Comment: @user2498668 If it returns a string, is it a string of XML or JSON? If it is XML it can be parsed in the C# code or in T-SQL, and if JSON then you will need to parse in C# unless you are planning on using SQL Server 2016. But currently your TVF is returning a result set of the fields as defined in `ResultRow`, so you either need to parse the data into that or consider a new structure. Why a list of strings? Unless you mean doing a simple split of the return value from the Web Service, in which case that is also fine. If you posted the return from the web service I could be more specific.